# Test multiple listeners with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I need to test every listener in a controller with Jasmine 2.0, really this question is just to reinforce my logic, and perhaps there is a more elegant way to approach testing listeners, or maybe I am being too thorough!

This might be a better question for codereview but I'll leave it here. How to properly test multiple keypress/event listeners in a controller effectively?

```
it("should trigger the correct actions from key events", function () {
    var listenerSpy = jasmine.createSpy('listenerSpy');
    angular.forEach(scope.$$listeners, function (fn, eventName) {
        listenerSpy(eventName, fn);
        expect(listenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(eventName, fn);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have above is not really testing anything other than JavaScript itself. You are calling a function and then expecting that you just called that function.

A code coverage report would show that the listener function has not executed at all.

Without seeing the code you are testing, I am unable to properly advise on how to structure your test.

There are two possible intentions:

1) Do you want to test that the scope is listening to a set of known elements?
2) Do you want to test the outcome of listener executions?

Usually, it would be best to take path number two, because with it, you also get number one.

Are all of your listeners performing the same action?

If they are, it may make sense to loop through a list of known elements and change them to verify the proper listener execution output.

If the listeners perform differently, each execution's output should be evaluated.

Comment: Every listener is a $scope.$on which has a callback that is a private function in the controller's scope, $$listeners returns an object which keys are the function, and value is the event name. This simply just tests that each listener is properly executing their respective callbacks.

Comment: This test is the same as spyOn(angular, 'noop'); angular.noop(someVar); expect(angular.noop).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someVar);

Comment: Correct, so I guess the question is, how to test if a certain function was actually called recursively

Comment: A) you can loop through the $$listeners and execute fn(newValue, oldValue) and verify the result. B) You can loop through an array of scope properties, edit them, $digest, and verify output. When iterating with expectations, it is a good idea to also have an expectation that the method which contains your expectation was called. Otherwise, if you have 0 iterations your test passes. For example, if you removed all the listeners.

Comment: it also appears that spyOn(scope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough(); does the same thing

Comment: I realized the problem with doing manual $broadcast(s) is that they aren't fully digested until ~150ms later, I'm just trying to keep my code as clean as possible

Comment: You can force a digest using $scope.$digest() or $scope.$apply() which will manually force a scope digest which includes processing broadcasts.